# Complex Analysis Book: Conway vs Lang

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation

I want to start stuyding complex analysis on a graduate level on my own (self study). I'm having trouble with diciding which one of the following books to use:

- Serge Lang's Complex Analysis
  or
- John. B. Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable.

Here's the first part of the contents of both books:

[image]

As you can see, Conway has a chapter on Metric Spaces and the Topology of $\Bbb C$, and starts with power series in the third chapter, while Lang does it directly in the second chapter.

Which of these two books do you guys recommend me and why?

Comment: I don't know if my recommendation will be useful for you but when I took Complex Analysis I followed a book called Basic Complex Analysis by Marsden and Hoffman. The book is beautiful and have a lot of examples and exercises of various levels. About the books that you are considering, I prefer Conway's book. In fact, you can follow Conway and complement it with Marsden.

Comment: For self-study, Conway’s textbook is better since it has more explanations assuming only single variable calculus as opposed to Lang’s textbook

Comment: Lang is a good book, but I would advise you to use Conway or Ahlfors (my personal choice) if you're learning it for the first time.